# Spivak's 'Calculus', 5-21(b): Is there an easier/shorter way?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

**Some personal background**: I'll be going into my second year as a maths undergraduate in September of this year, and I'm currently working my way through Spivak's *Calculus*. While $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments have been introduced in the course, certainly nothing like this question has been thrown at me yet, but I enjoy the challenge. In the *Supplement*, Spivak merely says the result is obvious, and gives no working; while it is intuitive, I wouldn't say this answer occurred to me immediately.

**The problem** is as follows:

Prove that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)g(x)$ also does not exist.

Prior to this, in Problem 21-5(a), it is proved that the same result holds if instead we assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$ exists and is nonzero, but I don't think this result is immediately relevant.

Please note that 'the limit exists' is taken to mean that function tends to some *finite* limit.

**My answer** is as follows:

Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)g(x)=l$, for some $l\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon>0$.

By hypotheses, we can find $\delta_{1},\delta_{2}>0$ such that $|f(x)|>(\epsilon + |l|)/\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x|<\delta_{1}$, and $|f(x)g(x)-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x|<\delta_{2}$. Note that $(\epsilon + |l|)/\epsilon\geq1>0$.

By the Triangle Inequality, we have $|f(x)g(x)| \leq |f(x)g(x)-l|+|l|$ always, so that $|f(x)g(x)|-|l| \leq |f(x)g(x)-l|$ always.

Also, when $0<|x|<\delta_{1}$, we have $|g(x)|(\epsilon+|l|)/\epsilon < |f(x)g(x)|$.

Hence, if we take $\delta = \mathrm{min}\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$, then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 < |x| < \delta & \Rightarrow & |f(x)g(x)-l| < \epsilon \\
& \Rightarrow & |f(x)g(x)| - |l| < \epsilon \\
& \Rightarrow & |f(x)g(x)| < \epsilon + |l| \\
& \Rightarrow & |g(x)|\cdot\frac{\epsilon+|l|}{\epsilon} < \epsilon + |l| \\
& \Rightarrow & |g(x)| < \epsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=0$.

Thus, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=0$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)g(x)$ exists. Therefore, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)g(x)$ also does not exist, provided $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|f(x)|=\infty$.

**My questions to you**: is there any shorter way of proving this, given the tools available (knowledge of definitions and inequalities, mostly)? More importantly, is my solution correct? Any feedback at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)}.
$$
The denominator tends to infinity,${}^1$ and if the numerator tends to a limit, then...

${}^1$Take absolute values if you really want to be precise.

Comment: I accepted this answer previously, but taking a look again I'm no longer convinced that this is enough. "Taking absolute values" seems to entail trying to prove that $g(x)$ tends to a limit whenever $\text{sgn}(f(x))g(x)$ does. This does not look pleasant (and I'm not sure it's even true), because we have to account for pathological choices of $f$, and we don't have much to work with when it comes to $g$ either.

I will keep this answer as "accepted", because, to be honest, I would be surprised if Spivak was expecting students to consider the problem so thoroughly when he put it in the book.

Comment: @WillR I am not sure if I have understood your comment. First of all, that exercise is marked with two stars. However, it seems to me that I gave you all the ingredients to write down a complete proof, assuming that 'having a limit' means 'having a finite limit'. Indeed, if you assume that the numerator converges to some $\ell \in \mathbf{R}$, then $|g(x)| \to |\ell|/\infty =0$. By a previous exercise in Spivak's book, this is equivalent to $g(x) \to 0$.

Comment: My sincerest apologies, you are entirely correct. I had not checked StackExchange until it occurred to me just now that I had missed the obvious way of doing things - perhaps I even saw this at the time and simply forgot it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to claim the result is false, since the author is allowing $\infty$ as a limit in the statement of the problem. A countexample is
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, x\ne 0, g(x) = 1, x > 0, g(x) = 2, x< 0.$$
Then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \infty,\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ doesn't exist, but $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x) = \infty.$

Comment: I thought about this too, but I think the limit being infinity is considered to "not exist" in this context. So the limit of $|f|$ doesn't exist either, but it doesn't exist in a very specific way. The problem should have been stated more clearly such that the limit of $fg$ either doesn't exist or diverges.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should have been more specific. In the text, $\infty$ is not taken to be a limit that 'exists'. I have edited my question to avoid any further confusion.